# Django limit choice of user field foreign key based on the user that logged in

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I have a model called Client with user field as a foreign key:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_('Client Name'), max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(_('Client Address'), max_length=100, blank=True)
    demand = models.PositiveIntegerField(_('Client Demand'))
    location = models.PointField(_('Client Location'))
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )

    class Meta:
        default_permissions = ('add', 'change', 'delete', 'view')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to limit the choice of the user field in the admin form based on who logged in

[image: django admin form]

for example, here I logged in as agung, so I want the select box choice of user field limit only to agung, but here I can access other username like admin and rizky.

I tried this

```
class ClientAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Client
        fields = "__all__"


    def __init__(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientAdminForm, self).__init__(request, *args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.fields['user'].queryset = request.user
```

but it seems that it can't take request as an argument (I guess because this is not an Http request)

Comment: Can you share the view where you use this form?

Comment: I used this in my ClientAdmin class, by assigning form=ClientAdminForm.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overwrite your Admin Model's `get_form` method to add the current `request.user` as class property. Next you can read it in the Form's constructor and filter the query.

```py
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # [...]
    
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        form_class = super(ClientAdmin, self).get_form(request, obj, **kwargs)
        form_class.set_user(request.user)

        return form_class


class ClientAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # [...]

    @classmethod
    def set_user(cls, user):
        cls.__user = user

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ClientAdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['user'].queryset = \
            self.fields['user'].queryset.filter(pk=self.__user.pk)
```

However, is easiest exclude this field in form and update it in the `save_model` method:

```py
class ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # [...]
    
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, the latter method works for me, just by adding save_model function directly to my ClientAdmin class.

Comment: You’re welcome @Agung! I wanted to write `ClientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin)` instead of `ClientAdminForm` in the last code. I've corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by override the base_fields attribute of your form instance like this :

*views.py*

```
# Before instantiate the form class
 ClientAdminForm.base_fields['user'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=self.request.user)

# Now you can instantiate the form
form = ClientAdminForm(...)
```

**NB :** Do override the base_fields just before instantiate the form